# Replicating the Foreground/Background Jitter from Photoshop in Corel Painter

Tags: adobe-photoshop, corel-painter

I was recently introduced to a set of Photoshop brushes that cleverly use the Foreground/Background Jitter (jittering between the foreground and background colors) to create a fur texture quickly. I've been trying some ways to do this in Corel, but the closest I've managed so far requires making a new custom gradient every time I switch colors. Does anyone know if there's some similar capability in Painter that I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have since learned the trick to this. If you use the Image Hose brush, you can tell it to [jitter between the Main and Additional color](http://product.corel.com/help/Painter/540213829/Main/EN/Win-Documentation/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm#context=Corel_Painter&file=Corel-Painter-Image-hose-opacity-additional-color.html).

> To adjust the color of image hose elements
>
> 1. In the Color panel, double-click the Additional Color swatch.
> 2. Choose a color from the Color dialog box.
> 3. On the property bar, move the Additional Color slider.
>
> You can also vary the additional color that is mixed with the nozzle images by moving the Additional Color Jitter slider on the
> property bar.

This will require a bit more work for the import of the Photoshop brush because you will have to export it as an image, and then import that image for the Image Hose.